# How to access an image when using Aurelia Webpack skeleton

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I have a project that I started from Aurelia's skeleton-esnext-webpack starter project.

In the static folder, I added my own folder called images and added 3 or 4 .png files.

Now, in my views, I'm trying to access one of those images:

```
<img src="./static/images/blk_leaves.png">
```

I consistently get an error (both during webpack compilation and in the browser) about not being able to resolve that path.

I don't understand webpack configuration well enough to know what is happening, but I do see a line that seems to indicate its trying to do something with .png files:

```
{ test: /\.(png|gif|jpg|cur)$/i, loader: 'url-loader', options: {limit: 8192} }
```

It doesn't appear that webpack is copying the images into the dist folder (where everything else goes). What do I need to do to get this to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use relative paths to load your images (and other assets for which you have registered [loaders](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/))

for instance, in the starter project, if you were loading your image in src/app.html, you can try..

```
<img src="../static/images/blk_leaves.png">
```